# How to check for an @ in an email address from a form post

Tags: php, forms, email, authentication, verification

I have a form with login and registration.

**My Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="mail" value="Input your email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Check"/>
</form>
```

If someone enters their email, I want to check if there is an `@` in the address. I have tried using an array, but that is not working.

Comment: if you want to check on `Login.php` page then `strpos($_POST['mail'],'@' != false){'mail contains @ character';}`. if you want to validate on the same page then some jquery.

Comment: _"will use "array""_ An' array doesn't have anything to do with checking whether your input field contains a @.

Comment: How do you want to do this? You could do it with JS, PHP, or HTML5. Client side, server side? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Do you want to validate the value which will be representing the email?

Comment: Or you check for a valid e-mail address using `filter_input()`...

Comment: filter_input(); is looking good, but i found only version with 'method="GET"'. Can i use it with POST ?

Source :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the php function `strpos` http://php.net/strpos

```
if(strpos($myEmailPostVariable, '@') === FALSE) {
    // do things here to say it failed
}
```

If you are fixed on using an array then you could use `explode`  http://php.net/explode

```
$parts = explode('@', $myEmailPostVariable);
if(count($parts) != 2) {
    // do things here to say it failed
}
```

Keep in mind the array way is not great as searching a string is easier and faster and is more readable.

As @jeroen has suggested if you want to validate the email then using `filter_input()` is the best...

```
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
    // do things here to say it failed
}
```